# Disable underline of inside element of underlined anchor tag

Tags: html, css

Can we Disable underline of inside span element of underlined anchor tag. If it is possible please tell me how?

```
 <a>hello<span>praveen</span</a>

 <style type="text/css>
     a{
        text-decoration:underline;
     }
     a span{
        text-decoration:none;
     }
 </style>
```

Comment: You cannot make with your current HTML structure. Try this http://jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/4oqyx6Le/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this.

add `display: inline-block;` for span style

```
a {
    text-decoration:underline;
}

a span {
    text-decoration:none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4oqyx6Le/2/

Answer (score 0):

a > span {
 text-decoration: none:
}

Comment: looks for the child element span of the parent a and will not assign any decoration to the element.

Comment: OP wants text-decoration:none for spans only inside underlined anchors